# How do I rewrite a number of URLs containing a common string to corresponding alternative path?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Quick question. I am currently making my first tentative few steps into the world of regex and I'm struggling with a URL rewrite i am attempting. Basically i need the rewrite rule to rewrite several urls all which will contain a common sub string and all of which will rewrite to the same sub path eg http://www.example.co.uk/test/folder will rewrite to http://www.example.co.uk/new/subfolder and http://dev.example.co.uk/new/subfolder will also rewrite to http://www.example.co.uk/new/subfolder etc. any body got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ /new/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(new/.+)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```